# Выбор даты рождения. Как реализовать?

Tags: php

Никак не могу найти, как реализовать три select бокса даты рождения, а точнее генерации данных в них. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
// Число
echo "<select name='sel_date'>";
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 31) {
    echo "<option value='" . $i . "'>$i</option>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</select>";
// Месяц
echo "<select name='sel_month'>";
$month = array(
    "Январь",
    "Февраль",
    "Март",
    "Апрель",
    "Май",
    "Июнь",
    "Июль",
    "Август",
    "Сентябрь",
    "Октябрь",
    "Ноябрь",
    "Декабрь"
);
foreach ($month as $m) {
    echo "<option value='" . $m . "'>$m</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
// Год
echo "<select name='sel_year'>";
$j = 1920;
while ($j <= 2020) {
    echo "<option value='" . $j . "'>$j</option>";
    $j++;
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может вам лучше использовать на jquery календарь? Посмотрите тут [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Comment: Выглядит очень ээфектно, просто мне бы не хотелось использовать jquery UI.

Comment: Тогда вам придется писать свой JavaScript, к сожалению я никогда не делал этого, а то бы поделился готовым.

Comment: Я просто видел подобное реализовывали, когда php наполняет даты, но сейчас нигде не нашел.